# Can I use WGET to generate a sitemap of a website given its URL?

Tags: php, wget, web-crawler, bots

I need a script that can spider a website and return the list of all crawled pages in plain-text or similar format; which I will submit to search engines as sitemap. Can I use WGET to generate a sitemap of a website? Or is there a PHP script that can do the same?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
wget --spider --recursive --no-verbose --output-file=wgetlog.txt http://somewebsite.com
sed -n "s@.\+ URL:\([^ ]\+\) .\+@\1@p" wgetlog.txt | sed "s@&@\&amp;@" > sedlog.txt
```

This creates a file called `sedlog.txt` that contains all links found on the specified website. You can use PHP or a shell script to convert the text file sitemap into an XML sitemap. Tweak the parameters of the wget command (accept/reject/include/exclude) to get only the links you need.

Comment: +1 Couldn't quite use it like that as it was giving me a bunch of errors (probably because of different wget/sed versions). But once I did some tweaking, it worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: You should add a small delay between requests using `--wait=1`, otherwise it might affect the performance of the site.

Comment: Combined with `tee` https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128476/312058 you can also see the output in stdout OR `tail -f` is even better

Comment: @Julian Yes, I had the same issue. On macOS, I had to use `gsed` instead of the builtin `sed`. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this perl script to do the trick : http://code.google.com/p/perlsitemapgenerator/

Comment: It'll generate by scanning file system but won't "crawl". The sites I want to spider are dynamic.