# Wget spider output

Tags: wget

Wget question:

Can  you help me understand what this means? Just pulling the urls to build a sitemap with:

> wget --spider --recursive --no-verbose --no-parent -t 3
>   --output-file=wgetlog.txt $URL

results in:

> 2013-06-17 18:56:54 URL:http:/domain/file/19[149408/149408] ->
>   "domain/file/19.1" [1]

Does this mean there is a redirect? Also, what do the numbers in the bracket mean? Why is there a second url with a `.1` at the end? and what does the `[1]` mean?

I have been searching documentation for a while, but did not find a page explaining output from **wget**. can someone help with any good link or explanation of above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use WGET to generate a sitemap of a website given its URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948947/can-i-use-wget-to-generate-a-sitemap-of-a-website-given-its-url)